# How to distinguish two objects Carbon\Carbon and Illuminate\Support\Carbon when getting mongoDB data in laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I have a question, but can't find an answer. So now I ask everyone to answer for me. If the question is not reasonable, please forgive me.

I am doing MongoBD with Laravel. My `updatedAt` field is saved as timestamp `1606789482` type `(int 32)`, and when I retrieve the data it will be as `object(Illuminate\Support\Carbon)` :

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $prodcut = Product::where('_id', '=', $request->data['_id'])->first()->toArray();
    dd($prodcut['updatedAt']);
    // result:
    //object(Illuminate\Support\Carbon)#1433 (3) {
     //["date"]=>
     //string(26) "2022-08-10 15:30:33.000000"
     //["timezone_type"]=>
     //int(3)
     //["timezone"]=>
     //string(3) "UTC"
    //}
}
```

But for some reason some of my productions save `updatedAt` as `ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")` type `(date)`. And when I get updatedAt it looks like this:

```
object(Carbon\Carbon)#1377 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2013-10-01 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

Is there a way to distinguish between `object(Illuminate\Support\Carbon)` and `object(Carbon\Carbon)` ?

Because when updating most successfully, But some products with updatedAt with type `date` got an error: `Object of class Carbon\\Carbon could not be converted to int` !

So I want to check if it is `date` `ISODate` then I will remove `updatedAt` before updating. Please give me your opinion. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Laravel (or the MongoDB library) is this? Laravel stopped using /Illuminate/Support/Carbon a while ago (the class is still there so 3rd party projects don't instantly break) so if you have code that uses it you should migrate it to use Carbon directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```php
    public function isIlluminateCarbon($param): bool
    {
        return (bool) ($param instanceof \Illuminate\Support\Carbon);
    }

    public function isCarbonCarbon($param): bool
    {
        return (bool) ($param instanceof \Carbon\Carbon);
    }

    // Call methods

    if ($this->isIlluminateCarbon($values)) {
        // is \Illuminate\Support\Carbon
    }

    if ($this->isCarbonCarbon($values)) {
        // is \Carbon\Carbon
    }
```